# Characteristic polynomial roots of $ 3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

How would you approach this problem?

Let $A$ be an orthogonal $3$ by $3$ matrix. That is, $A^TA = AA^T=I_3$. Prove that the characteristic polynomial $\textit{p}_A$ has a real root.

I am not familiar with how to prove a third degree polynomial has a real root. I started the problem by noticing that $\det(A-tI) = \det(A-tAA^T)=\det(A)\det(I-tA^T)$, but this isn't getting me anywhere.

Comment: Welcome  to Maths SX! All cubic polynomials have (at least) one real root, and this has nothing to do with orthogonal matrices: it relies on the *Intermediate value theorem*.

Comment: @Bernard: then the claim holds for all 3x3 matrices?

Comment: Over the field $\mathbf R$, yes.

Comment: @Bernard: I see, thanks!

Comment: @Bernard the intermediate value theorem? I thought it just followed from the fact that complex roots come in pairs.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist: That's a nicer, but more sophisticated argument: it supposes you've proved $\mathbf C$ is algebraically closed – which isn't exactly trivial.

Comment: @Bernard You're right, I am taking the fundamental theorem of algebra for granted. I've been doing that for so long (even well before I saw the proof) that I'd almost forgotten what you need to be able to prove it. That said, I'd never actually encountered the intermediate-value argument before. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned the characteristic polynomial of your matrix is a third degree polynomial and every third degree polynomial has a real root.

You do not have to prove that every third degree polynomial has a real root to solve your problem because it is a well-known fact by just looking at the end behavior of the polynomial.